# How to let API Gateway Proxy Error Responses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've got an API Gateway in front of a Lambda.

Successful responses from the Lambda (HTTP 2xx) have the response body forwarded.

However, for error responses (HTTP 5xx and others), the API Gateway transforms the response body using response templates.

Is there a way to avoid this? To have the original error response body from the Lambda?

In my Lambda I have this:

```
return callback(generalError, {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers:{
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                error: 'INTERNAL_ERROR',
                description: error.message,
            })
        });
```

However, as output from the Gateway I get this:

```
{ "error": "Internal server error" }
```

Which doesn't match. The Lambdas response. It does match the response template in API Gateway:

```
{"message":$context.error.messageString}
```

However, is there a way to just proxy the original Lambda response instead of having this transformation in place?

Comment: What is `generalError`? Also, I'm not aware that `return callback(...)`  would cause a problem (specifically that you use return there) but I'd avoid it if possible. And see [Handle custom Lambda errors in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html).

Comment: @jarmod It's just a json object, even replacing it with a text string won't work because it gets replaced by the gateway response template. I'll take a look at that link thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason why it doesn't work.

If you set a callback to a 500 error, including an object with an `error` field, somehow this will become the full response, regardless of the other output or real error.

Avoiding using an `error` field does the trick! I renamed it to `serviceError` and now I'm getting the responses I expected.